# How to implement XLIFF file format in to PHP?

Tags: php, xml, open-source

Can any one please let me know how to implement `XLIFF` file format in to PHP? as of my knowledge it is for `multilingual web development concept for CMS based projects`. But not sure how it is to be implement on PHP i.e the methodology of reading/writing content into this XML file.

Please let me know if any other reference, URLs, books will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Zend Framework has a reader for this translation string format. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html  -- Or was your question on how you personally want to reimplement such a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a XLIFF implementation into Zend Framework: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

Here's another implementation: http://code.google.com/p/goatherd-php-library/